# Lie algebra convert into a category?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I already saw examples, where we ''converted'' a group G into a category with one object and the morphisms are exactly the group elements and the composition of the morphisms equals the composition of the group.
Analogously we can ''convert'' a K-algebra in such a so called K-linear category with one object, but the morphismset is now a K-vectorspace, with... You know what I mean. 
Is there a similarly construction with Lie-algebras?

My main goal is to motivate representation theory of these objects (already done for groups and K-algebras - they are just the functors into Vect_K).

Maybe one of you could help me? Maybe as simple as possible, since I'm a newbie regarding Category theory. Thank you for your time :)

Edit: My K-algebras are associative and have a unital element.

Comment: Can you expand on $k$-algebras as functors to $\operatorname{Vect}_k$?

Comment: Expand what exactly?

Comment: Functors from what category to $\operatorname{Vect}_k$

Comment: Oh sorry, consider the group G as a category C described above. Than any functor from C to $Vect_K$ is a representation of G (and vice versa). Analogously for K-algebras (here the functors should be K-linear). Now I want an analogue for Lie algebras.

Comment: Since you are interested in representations, you could just replace the Lie algebra by its universal enveloping algebra.

Comment: I want to motivate the definition without any higher results.

Comment: I see inevitable to turn the Lie algebra (perhaps in some implicit way) to its enveloping algebra if you want to see it as some category, since *associativity* is a key ingredient of categories.

Comment: Hmm that's a good point Berci, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Lie algebras do not lend themselves to a direct translation into some sort of category with one object, because associativity is built into the definition of categories.

However, they do *act* in very interesting ways on categories, and this has led to some of the most interesting connections between various areas of representation theory. Here is the fundamental example: consider representations of the symmetric group $S_n$ over a field $F$ of positive characteristic $p$. Write $C_n$ for the category of such representations. There is a bi-adjoint pair of functors of restriction and induction $E:C_n \to C_{n-1}$ and $F:C_{n-1} \to E_n$ that relate the various categories as $n$ varies.

Evidently any element of the centralizer of the group algebra $F S_{n-1}$ in $F S_n$ acts by endomorphisms on the functors $E$ and $F$. It turns out that the $S_{n-1}$ orbit sum
$$\phi_n=(1n)+(2n)+\cdots+(n-1,n)$$ together with the center of $FS_{n-1}$ generates this centralizer (this is sometimes referred to as the $n$th *Jucys-Murphy-Young* element).

The possible eigenvalues of $\phi_n$ are the elements $0,1,\dots,p-1$ of the prime field $F_p=\mathbf{Z}/p \mathbf{Z}$ of $F$. Decomposing $E$ and $F$ into eigen-functors gives bi-adjoint pairs $(E_0,F_0),\dots,(E_{p-1},F_{p-1})$. On the level of Grothendieck groups, the operators induced by these produce a highest weight representation of the affine Lie algebra $\widehat{\mathfrak{sl}}_p$. There is an additional piece of structure that is also important for this story: the endomorphism of the functor $E^2$ given by the simple transposition $(n,n+1)$; together with the action of the Jucys-Murphy-Young elements this produces an action of an (degenerate) affine Hecke algebra.

All these ideas are present in Grojnowski's beautiful paper *Affine $\mathfrak{sl}_p$ controls the modular representation theory of the symmetric group and related Hecke algebras*. These ideas were further developed and used to prove Broué's conjecture on derived equivalences between blocks of different symmetric groups in Chuang-Rouquier's landmark *Derived equivalences for symmetric groups and $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-categorification*. Since these foundational works, the area has exploded. The key words to look for are $2$-categories and higher representation theory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not hear about these things that you mentioned. But the first and the last paragraph are enough for me :D